# React costructor does not work

Tags: reactjs

consider this react class

```
var sentence = "The FBI has managed to unlock the iPhone";

define(["./UserInput","./Statistic","./RandomWords","react", "react-dom"],
  (UserInput,Statistic,RandomWords,React, ReactDOM) => {

      var Root = React.createClass({
        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log("Hey");
            this.state={sentenct: sentence }

          }

    render: function() {
          return (
            <div >

                <h1>Welcome to our game</h1>
                <UserInput/>
                <RandomWords NewWord={ sentence }/>
                <Statistic   speed={"Salman"}  success={"saba"} />
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Root, null),
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
});
```

I have tried [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), and
I made a costructor, and i expect to see the "Hey" in my console but it does not happen?

Comment: Why dont you use ES6 at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this.state.sentence` instead of variable

```
var sentence = "The FBI has managed to unlock the iPhone";

    render: function() {
              return (
                <div >

                    <h1>Welcome to our game</h1>
                    <UserInput/>
                    <RandomWords NewWord={ this.state.sentence }/>
                    <Statistic   speed={"Salman"}  success={"saba"} />
                </div>
              );
    }
```

And `ReactDOM` doens't require element, but class

```
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

If issue still exists, write in comment sections below, willing to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Classes which created by `React.createClass` does not have `constructor` method.
Only ES6-classes have `constuctor` method.

Example:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Hey");
        this.state={sentenct: sentence }
    }
}
```